# Why export * and import * work differently in ES2015 module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module

In ES2015 module, `export * from 'someModule'` does not export the default export from 'someModule', while `import * as m from 'someModule'` imports the default export from 'someModule'.

For example, in module.js:

```
export default 'default'
export const foo = 'foo'
```

in proxy.js:

```
export * from './module'
```

in bar.js:

```
import * as m from './module'  // m is { foo: 'foo', default: 'default' }
import * as p from './proxy'  // p is { foo: 'foo' }
```

I've tested it using webpack 4.29.6 (zero configuration).

and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) writes:

> The following syntax does not export a default export from the
>   imported module:
>
> export * from …;
>
> If you need to export the default, write the following instead:
>
> export {default} from 'mod';

It's reasonable for `export * from 'someModule'` not exporting the default export from 'someModule', since the current module might also want to export its own default module. But why `import *` includes the default export anyway? Is it the expected behavior from ES2015 module specification?

Comment: It seems logic to me that `import *` includes everything that's been exported. If there is a reason that there is a difference between the 2 exports (and you stated it), it's normal it reflects on the import. (and if it was the other way, default would **always** be missing, if you think about it)

Comment: I was surprised that the `*` in import statement and the `*` in export statement do not mean the same thing. I got the wrong idea before ever trying it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But why `import *` includes the default export anyway?

The module namespace object includes all exports of the module. There is nothing special about the identifier `default` here. There's no reason to explicitly omit it.

> Is it the expected behavior from ES2015 module specification?

Yes.

> It's reasonable for `export * from 'someModule'` not exporting the default export from 'someModule', since the current module might also want to export its own default module.

Afaik, the actual reason for the exception is so that you can `export *` from multiple modules without having their `default` exports collide.